# Passing set to templatised function

Tags: c++, templates, set

Here's my complete working code

```
class Point2D
{
    protected:
        int x, y;

    public:
        Point2D(int x_, int y_) : x(x_), y(y_)
        {
        }

        int getX() const
        {
            return x;
        }

        int getY() const
        {
            return y;
        }

        bool operator< (const Point2D & pointObj) const
        {
            if(x == pointObj.getX() && y == pointObj.getY())
                return false;

            return pointObj.getX() == x ? true : x < pointObj.getX();

        }

};

template<typename T, typename U>
void printSet(const set<T>& setToPrint)
{
    set<T, U> pSet;
    for(typename set<T>::iterator it = setToPrint.begin(); it != setToPrint.end(); it++)
    {
        pSet.insert(*it);
    }
    for(typename set<T,U>::iterator it = pSet.begin(); it != pSet.end(); it++)
    {
        //here print the element
    }
}
int main()
{
    set<Point2D> setP2;
    setP2.insert(Point2D(1,3));
    setP2.insert(Point2D(3,2));

    int i = 1;
    if(i==1)
    {
        printSet<Point2D, std::less<Point2D > >(setP2);
        i++;
    }
    if(i==2)
    {
        printSet<Point2D, std::greater<Point2D > >(setP2);
    }
}
```

It produces a bunch of errors from template code, but I think below is the primary one

> /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_function.h:377:20: error: no match for ‘operator>’ (operand types are ‘const Point2D’ and ‘const Point2D’)
>   /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_function.h:377:20: note:   ‘const Point2D’ is not derived from ‘const std::pair<_T1, _T2>’

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to create `std::set<Point2D, std::greater<Point2D>>`, you need to implement `operator>` between two objects of type `Point2D`.

Add a member funtion similar to `operator<` in the class to resolve the problem.

#### Suggestion for improvement

The `operator<` function can be simplified to user fewer compare operations.

```
bool operator< (const Point2D & pointObj) const
{
   if ( x != pointObj.x )
   {
      return ( x < pointObj.x );
   }

   return ( y < pointObj.y );
}
```

The `operato>` function can be similarly implemented as:

```
bool operator> (const Point2D & pointObj) const
{
   if ( x != pointObj.x )
   {
      return ( x > pointObj.x );
   }

   return ( y > pointObj.y );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have implemented the `<` operator, not the `>`. C++ is pretty particular about that kind of thing. Implement `operator>` and you should be all set.
You can do that in terms of `operator<` if you like:

```
 bool operator> (const Point2D & pointObj) const
        {
            if(x == pointObj.getX() && y == pointObj.getY())
                return false;

            return pointObj < this;

        }
```

You can see more examples [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/105805).